# Unable to enable core modules - Magento

Tags: magento

I unfortunately disabled the entire modules list including the core modules under

`Admin->System->Configurations->Advanced->Disable Modules Output`

And once I tried to retrieve it back, I have seen blank page in the above path.

I followed below thread but still site not working

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/73558/

Also I checked the entire files inside `app/etc/modules/` and noticed that every xml file has the active tag value as true `<active>true</active>`

As I'm in the learning curve of Magento, I have no idea where and all the module enabling entry resides. Please someone pinpoint what should be done to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check the core_config_data table in your database:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "advanced/modules_disable_output/%"
```

I guess there will be "1" in the "value" column. Change it to "0" for modules you want to be enabled. Then you'll probably need to clear caches - not sure if you can do it via backend but you can still delete files under your var/cache folder if you are using file cache storage.